# ReactJS Bracket Syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to learning reactJS and am confused as to when to use the brackets within components.

For example, how how do I know to use brackets around props.name?

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: When you want to use javascript expressions inside anything jsx, use the `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to React!

Those brackets fall are JSX syntax. JSX was invented by Facebook for React. See this page for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

And the spec: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Of note:

> You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX